# How to get a specific (deep) value from json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need know correct sintax to retrive the highlighted value:

[image: facebook graph]

I can get the other values correctly:

```
$result=json_decode($data);
$ret['like'] = $result->likes->summary->total_count;
$ret['original_date'] = $result->created_time;
$ret['url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com'.$result->permalink_url;
```

but i don't know how to get:

```
$ret['views'] = $result-> video_insights -> 0 -> values -> 0 -> value (?)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't do `->0`, it's an array not an object.

Comment: Use foreach loops - foreach($result-> video_insights->data as $x){ etc...

Comment: As miken32 mentions you need to use arrays at some points - `$ret['views'] = $result-> video_insights->data[0] -> values[0] -> value`